# How to change color of text in canvas in phaser.js?

Tags: phaser

I want to change the text color in my game that is build in phaser.js. But i have no idea how to do this, because i am not a coder.

Can somebody help me to change the color of my game text?

My Game is http://games.eyebraingym.com/slotreading/

I want to change the color on the canvas where the heading is 'Slot Reading'.

Answer (score 1):

In your source code "game.js" (http://games.eyebraingym.com/slotreading/states/game.js) there are multiple lines that look like

```
text_line[l].addColor("#e6e6e6",0);
```

here, the "#e6e6e6" is the color. If you aren't familiar with CSS hexadecimal colors, there are sites like https://htmlcolorcodes.com/ where you can pick out a color.

You'll have to find a new color, for example, "#FF0000" for red, and replace all the old instances of "#e6e6e6" with "#FF0000".

Comment: Thanks for your reply jimmy. I have made the changes and refreshed page with ctr+f5 but no changes are made. Can you please advice me on this ?

Comment: look at the example pages on github for phaser.  that would be your best reference for code resource tactics.